# Should I handle EINTR while reading a file in /proc

Tags: c, linux

In Linux `read()` call can return `-1` and put `EINTR` into `errno`. I understand why it can happen for a pipe or socket.
But what about files in proc filesystem? Can we really get `EINTR` while reading them?

I tried to search in open sources and found that somewhere it is handled:

https://github.com/Distrotech/libaudit/blob/distrotech-libaudit/lib/libaudit.c#L700
https://github.com/mmalecki/procps/blob/master/proc/readproc.c#L517

But somewhere not:

https://github.com/slicer69/sysvinit/blob/master/sysvinit/trunk/src/bootlogd.c#L303

Does it depend on specific file in /proc and if yes where can I read about this? Or this handling is always superfluous or maybe is it a bug to skip handling `EINTR`?

Comment: AFAICT any system call is at least theoretically capable of return EINTR; whether or not you can get away with ignoring that possible outcome in practice for any given call is not easily knowable; it might be the case today but not in the next version of the OS, or vice versa.  Related:  https://blog.reverberate.org/2011/04/eintr-and-pc-loser-ing-is-better-case.html

Comment: Does your program register any custom signal handlers? If not, then other than a few buggy things like epoll and io_uring, you'll never get `EINTR` from any syscall.

Comment: Yes, it handles signals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `read` makes no distinction between the underlying filesystems, it can return `-1` no matter what. Hence, you should handle it.

*How* you handle it is up to you. For example, you may opt to exit your program, notifying the user of the failure. Or you may retry the `read` assuming that it's a temporary issue, something like:

```
int interrupted = 1, limit = 5, result;
while (interrupted) {
    result = read(...);
    interrupted = (result == -1) && (errno == EINTR) && (limit-- > 0);
}
```

That will try to read the file a number of times before giving up (assuming the failure cause is `EINTR` - any other cause exits the loop immediately). When the loop exits, you either have a successful read (`result > 0`) or an unsuccessful one with `errno` set to the reason).

You could also refactor that code into a function to do the heavy lifting for you, such as with a function I've used for this purpose before:

```
ssize_t interruptibleRead(
    int     fd,             // Standard read parameters.
    void    *buf,
    size_t  count,
    size_t  limit,          // Maximum attempts.
    size_t  msDelay,        // Initial delay after interrupted read.
    size_t  msDelayDelta    // Extra delay added for each interrupted read.
);
```

This would prevent having to pepper your code with complex loops, it just becomes a matter of replacing `read` calls with `interruptibleRead`.